# Возможно ли изменить выходной путь проекта Visual Studio через переменную

Tags: c++, visual-studio, компиляция

Возможно ли изменить путь к папке, куда будет компилироваться проект в Visual Studio? В свойствах проекта я знаю как это сделать, но мне нужно изменить путь через код на C++.

И я знаю что это можно очень легко сделать с помощью CMake, но я к сожалению использую IDE и урезать ее функционал до обычного текстового редактора используя CMake как-то не очень хочется.

А также дополнительный вопрос: возможно ли запустить сборку проекта из runtime'а другого проекта. Через CMake я предполагаю что это можно сделать вызвав в C++ коде .bat файл или другой работающий с консолью файл. А вот как быть с сборщиком Visual Studio? Или там тоже можно через консоль скомпилировать проект?

Comment: Студийные проекты компилируются из консоли вызовом `devenv.exe солюшн /Build` (или что-то в этом духе).

Comment: О опять ты, привет). Спасибо. А на основной вопрос не знаешь ответа? Вроде я в MSDN видел что такое возможно сделать, но там Visual Basic использовался, а c++ я не нашел

Comment: *"нужно изменить путь через код на C++"* - ¿но зачем? И тут не понятно, о чем идет речь, о настройке пути для сборки этого файла С++, или о просто вызове сборки других проектов при выполнении кода С++. А вообще да, все можно собрать через консоль, причем как с nmake / msbuild, так и с прямым вызовом компилятора и прочих инструментов.

Comment: Про это не знаю. Может просто скопировать результаты билжения в нужное место? Еще, мне кажется, msbuild и формат студийных проектов - вселенское зло (хотя CMake тоже, но в меньшей степени), и я бы от студийных проектов избавился. *"урезать ее функционал до обычного текстового редактора"* А что урезается? Подсказки по коду работают, дебаггер тоже. Флаги нельзя из гуи менять? По мне это мелочи.

Comment: Нет, я понимаю, что затейники, они всякие бывают... И все же — ***зачем???***

Comment: Я делаю движок. И сейчас я делаю систему сборки конечного проекта (игры) в решении моего движка в Visual Studio у меня находятся два проекта один который отвечает именно за все компоненты игры, а другой чисто за редактор движка. Так вот проект отвечающий за игру, будет скомпилирован в dll и exe-файлы по пути, который укажет пользователь в редакторе движка при сборке его проекта, а редактор... а редактор будет компилироваться как обычная программа. Вот и все :). Я конечно до конца еще не продумал как это будет работать и будет ли вообще оно так работать, но надеюсь будет

Comment: А я так понимаю, вы все используете CMake?

Comment: Я планирую добавить поддержку Cmake, но он будет как второй вариант сборки. Да и к тому же я не буду сам писать CmakeLists.txt, а буду пользоваться конвертером из самого CMake

Comment: Мне кажется, вам в вашем редакторе стоит генерировать проект и указывать там, куда оно должно собираться. Ну или даже собирать все самостоятельно (если весь код будет сгенерирован) - там где вам захочется. Я (по возможности) стараюсь CMake не использовать.

Comment: Кстати, я прочитал что еще можно собирать проект Visual Studio через консоль с помощью программы MSBuild. Мда... То есть чтобы собрать проект от студии нужно еще какой-то софт качать. Ладно, наверное придется учить CMake, ведь по любому в любой компании его знать обязательно. Можете посоветовать книги по современному CMake? Желательно чтобы она была не большая)

Comment: И кстати мне все больше кажется, что такими темпами я подбираюсь все ближе и ближе к UNIX системам

Comment: Вообще-то это студия собирает проекты MSBuild c помощью MSBuild. И чтобы собрать этот проект как раз нет необходимости качать саму студию.

Comment: MSBuild ставится вместе со студией. Но лучше из консоли собирать не им (потому что он тормознутый), а самой студией (`devenv.exe`, как выше писал).

Comment: да всё уже. Я начал осваивать CMake и vcpkg. Но спасибо всем за помощь :)